# How to set BackgroundTintList of a button to default?

Tags: java, android, button

I'm changing the BackgroundTintList property of my button with the following line.

```
myButton.setBackgroundTintList(getColorStateList(R.color.green));
```

As a result my Button changes it's color from grey to green, and this is what I'd like to achieve.

My problem is that later on I'd like to set back the original grey color of the button, but I have no idea how to do it. I have tried to get the BackgroundTintList property of the button at the very beginning of my code (before I change it) but the following line returns NULL

```
ColorStateList buttonBackgroundTint = myButton.getBackgroundTintList();
```

Once I have set the BackgroundTintList to green, setting it to NULL changes my button to white and not to its default grey.

What would be the way to set my button to grey again?

Comment: Try to set background color of the button to 0

Answer (score 9):

You can try this line:

```
myButton.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#d8d8d8")));
```

if you want to change the button color back to its default/original color.

Comment: This techically answers my question, so thanks. I will keep looking for a generic solution though cause if the default tint is anything different than this then the color constant is different again.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't found any way to do this easily. The only way I could accomplish your goal was to hold on to the original background `Drawable`, create a clone of it, manually tint the clone, and then swap back and forth between these new drawables.

```
private Drawable original;
private Drawable tinted;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    this.original = button.getBackground();
    this.tinted = button.getBackground().getConstantState().newDrawable().mutate();

    ColorStateList custom = getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.my_button, getTheme());
    tinted.setTintList(custom);

    ...
}
```

Then later on I can either write `button.setBackground(original)` or `button.setBackground(tinted)` to swap between the two.

Comment: Old answer but thanks a lot. I think this should be correct answer because it seems to correctly store and restore the original settings of the button you have and does try to rewrite them with some information from some side-channel!

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new `Button` and get `backgroundTintList`

```
actionSearch.backgroundTintList = MaterialButton(requireContext()).backgroundTintList
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want add custom color

```
view.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(getColor(context, R.color.color)
```